# subsetting a dataset using dplyr filter condition

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I want to subset a dataframe to collect information from all the columns.

I will explain the question using the `msleep` dataset.

```
library(msleep)
```

I looked at the frequency of the frequency of a column `genus` to look at the distribution of the frequencies.

```
msleep %>% count(genus) %>% count(n)
## A tibble: 3 × 2
#      n    nn
#  <int> <int>
#1     1    73
#2     2     2
#3     3     2
```

I would like to extract all the rows in the main column having value exactly twice.

```
msleep %>% count(genus) %>% filter(n==2)
## A tibble: 2 × 2
#   genus     n
#   <chr> <int>
#1  Equus     2
#2 Vulpes     2
```

How to achieve the below expected output?

Expected output:

```
msleep[msleep$genus %in% c('Equus','Vulpes'),]
## A tibble: 4 × 11
#        name  genus  vore          order conservation sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle awake brainwt bodywt
#       <chr>  <chr> <chr>          <chr>        <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1      Horse  Equus herbi Perissodactyla domesticated         2.9       0.6        1.00  21.1  0.6550 521.00
#2     Donkey  Equus herbi Perissodactyla domesticated         3.1       0.4          NA  20.9  0.4190 187.00
#3 Arctic fox Vulpes carni      Carnivora         <NA>        12.5        NA          NA  11.5  0.0445   3.38
#4    Red fox Vulpes carni      Carnivora         <NA>         9.8       2.4        0.35  14.2  0.0504   4.23
```

Any alternative ways of getting the expected output are also appreciated.

ps: Are there any better ways of looking at the frequency of frequencies? or looking at the filter condition (here:n==2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `group_by` and then `filter` directly instead of going through the `count` approach

```
msleep %>%
      group_by(genus) %>%
      filter(n() ==2)
# A tibble: 4 x 11
# Groups: genus [2]
#        name  genus  vore          order conservation sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle awake brainwt bodywt
#       <chr>  <chr> <chr>          <chr>        <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1      Horse  Equus herbi Perissodactyla domesticated         2.9       0.6        1.00  21.1  0.6550 521.00
#2     Donkey  Equus herbi Perissodactyla domesticated         3.1       0.4          NA  20.9  0.4190 187.00
#3 Arctic fox Vulpes carni      Carnivora         <NA>        12.5        NA          NA  11.5  0.0445   3.38
#4    Red fox Vulpes carni      Carnivora         <NA>         9.8       2.4        0.35  14.2  0.0504   4.23
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. What is the best way of looking at the frequency of frequencies?

Comment: @Prradep  Sorry, I didn't get your question.  Did you meant to  get some proportion of frequencies?

Comment: Sorry for not communicating clearly. How to look at the distribution/summary of frequencies of values in column genus? I mean how to achieve the output of  `msleep %>% count(genus) %>% count(n)` in a better way?

Comment: @Prradep  If you do a second `count` on 'n', that will only provide the info about how many 1,2, and 3 and wouldn't give you `genus` which is the same as `table(table(msleep$genus))`

Comment: yes, I would require that first for having a glimpse of the data. It would help me to subset the data using your proposed solution(that's how I chose n=2 in this current example).

Comment: @Prradep  Using `table(table(msleep$genus))#

 1  2  3 
73  2  2 ` we get 73 1s, 2 2s and 2 3s.  From this you are selecting `2` because it is the max frequency for 2 and 3?

Comment: Yes, thanks. The base approach comes for rescue! Are there no fancy functions in dplyr?

Comment: @Prradep  For `count`, there is another function `tally` and `n()` after grouping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145365/discussion-between-prradep-and-akrun).